# What is dark blue "Ready" build phase in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, build, linker, visual-studio-2015

This is known Visual Studio build sequence – I'd like to identify action during 3rd image from above:

[image]

When I launch the application built in [visual-studio-2015](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015), status line turns dark blue saying `Build started...` (see second image). After some time, it is replaced by `Ready` (see 3rd image), but **nothing is actually ready**. Is it still the same build phase (just with initial `Build started...` label timed-out?) or is it some different phase of build? Where I can see what's behind the scenes?

Build output window says only:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>   1>  Project1 -> D:\path\Project1.exe
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

In this case, I was building single [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) project referencing couple of custom DLL's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each project in your solution builds, the status is reset to Ready. This also occurs after you click or move your cursor to a new section of code in the text editor. If it has to perform some sort of processing or if there is an error where the cursor is positioned you will see an appropriate message. Then if you move your cursor to another section of code without any issues the status will reset to Ready.

In your case, the difference between the Ready message you see and the final Orange Ready is that when you are debugging in VS, first the solution must build, then it sets the status to Ready, then there are post-build events that must execute to initialize the debugger. If you look at the status bar you will see messages quickly flashing like "Loading symbols for MyLibrary.dll". Once the debugging engine is initialized the status line turns orange.

To see what it is doing to initialize the debugger, take a look at your Output window and show output from "Debug". It will output all of the DLLs it is loading.

Comment: I do not quite understand your first sentence ("As each project in your solution builds, the status is reset to Ready"). I have only one project in the solution. There is some 10 seconds of `Build Started`, then there is 50 seconds of dark blue `Ready`. What is the VS doing that 50 seconds? In VS 2012, there were 20+5 seconds on the same project, where now is 10+50.

Comment: When it transitions from Build Started to Ready, that means your build has completed. The next 50 seconds are devoted to initializing the debugging engine. To see what VS is loading during those 50 seconds, take a look at your Output window, and make sure "Debug" is selected in the dropdown. The first line should be something like "Auto-attach to process '[856] w3wp.exe' on machine 'YourMachineName' succeeded.'" Followed by all of the DLLs that were loaded. Once the debugging engine has finished initializing, your status line changes to the color orange.

Comment: I phrased my response "As each project in your solution builds, the status is reset to Ready" for any future readers that are building a solution with more than one project.

Comment: Looking at Output window, when "Debug" is selected in the dropdown: it shows no results except inital message. Maybe VB.net builds differently from C#. Now I can see that `Build complete` briefly flashes at the end of dark blue "Ready" period. So during that 50 seconds, there was something different from debug engine init. Debug engine init looks to take < 1s on my Intel i7 PC+SSD drives.

Comment: Yeah, as far as the time discrepancy, 5 seconds vs. 50 seconds, that is unusual. My VS2015 debugger initializes in about 5 seconds for a solution with 22 projects. I suggest pinning your Output window so it is always visible then start the debugger. Select Debug from the dropdown so you can see what it is doing during those 50 seconds. Hopefully there you will be able to see what is taking so long. Maybe a specific DLL is causing some trouble.

Comment: One thing to check. In VS Options --> Debugging --> Output Window - make sure that "All debug output" is set to On.

Comment: In fact, make sure that all options under Output Window --> General Output Settings are set to On. The module load messages are the majority of the messages I see when the debugger is initializing.

Comment: Thank you for those output settings. Actually "Debug" view is still producing *nothing* (except of title) until debug mode is initialized, but at least I can see symbol loading (takes 0.2 sec) and other things.